# Does JKS supports keys created by Post Quantum algorithms like dilithium3?

Tags: openssl, certificate, keytool, jks, post-quantum-cryptography

I am trying to add my .pfx file to JKS using keytool command and its working with keys generated using RSA but not with keys generated using dilithium algorithm

command : keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore combined.pfx -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore keystore.jks

error : keytool error: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: 1.3.6.1.4.1.2.267.7.8.7 KeyFactory not available

Comment: This is not programming or development and is offtopic, but: the JKS format itself can contain any algorithm with X.509 and PKCS8 encodings, including Dilithium, but `keytool` can only handle algorithms implemented by the cryptoproviders in your JRE, and the 'standard' providers (those supplied in Oracle Java or OpenJDK) don't do that (yet). If you get the BouncyCastle provider jar (>= 1.73) and add keytool arguments `-providerclass org.bouncycastle.pqc.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastlePQCProvider -providerpath /loc/of/bcprov.jar` I think it will work (but can't easily test)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create a JKS keystores using dilithium3 post quantum algorithm. You need to have bouncycastle bcprov-jdk180n latest version Jar to be used as provider.

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias your_alias -storetype JKS -keyalg DILITHIUM3 -sigalg DILITHIUM3 -keystore your_keystore.jks -validity 365 -storepass your_keystore_password -keypass your_key_password -provider org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath /path/to/bcprov-jdk18on.jar
```